# Do I need to test the desktop layout on mobile if there is a mobile layout?

Tags: website-design, web-app, mobile-web

I'm making a website and the site will have a fully fleshed out mobile version. I'm just wondering if, from a user experience point of view I should verify that the desktop mode works as well?

Some users might opt to use the site's desktop version instead of the layout specifically made for mobile. Do I need to see the extra effort of tweaking the desktop version to accomodate those users who choose to use the desktop version on a tiny screen, or does it automatically become a given that it might not work as expected with the desktop layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, just do it, it won't harm.

If resources are scarce (yet you still can do it, even though reluctantly for costs and resources reasons), I'd suggest to **test if users are really using the desktop version on mobile**.

If they don't, or the percentage is negligible, maybe it would be enough with a notice *"this version is not optimized for your screen, please use the mobile version"*.

However, **if after testing the percentage is over 10%** (5 if you're over zealous) then yes, you must test it out